# How root can make sure that this time sudo will not prompt for password a specific user?

Tags: sudo, lxc

I am writing a script, that will setup `lxc` on the host, and then configure a container. I want this script to be unattended. After the container is created and run, there is a moment, when I want to log in as the user and perform some commands with `sudo`. I know how to setup ssh to let me login without asking any questions. The only bit that is left, is to make sure, that I can do the `sudo`.

I don't want to disable the `sudo` - I just want to mimic a situation, when the user actually puts the password.

So far I made the following:

```
if [ ! -d /var/lib/lxc/$puppetmastername/rootfs/var/lib/sudo/$user ]; then
    sudo mkdir /var/lib/lxc/$puppetmastername/rootfs/var/lib/sudo/$user
fi
sudo touch /var/lib/lxc/$puppetmastername/rootfs/var/lib/sudo/$user/0

sudo grep '!tty_tickets' /etc/sudoers
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo 'Defaults         !tty_tickets' >>/var/lib/lxc/puppetmaster/rootfs/etc/sudoers
fi
```

Unfortunately, it is insufficient, the container still asks for password.

Comment: Since you're effectively allowing your program to run arbitrary commands as root, why aren't you running it as root in the first place?

Comment: @Gilles because of the environment inheritance, that `sudo` provides.

Answer (score 0):

You must edit your `/etc/sudoers` file and grant your user permission to run some programs as root without password:

```
yourusername ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /path/to/prog1, /path/to/prog2, ...
```

In your case, you can try:

```
myusername ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /bin/mkdir, /usr/bin/touch, /bin/grep
```

You must check `NOPASSWD` entry is the last entry that match your user. If two entries in `/etc/sudoers` matches your user, `NOPASSWD` rule need to be after that one to take effects.

Comment: I know that technique, but it is troublesome - there is a lot of programs I need to run as root, and I want to run them only once. And I don't want to declare those programs in the `sudoers` file - this is error-prone.

Comment: You could change the list of commands to the word `ALL`. Then you don't need to list them all. Then once the configuration has ended, replace the `sudoers` file with a `sudoers` file that doesn't have that line that grants the user effective root access.